# Databinding using SQLite and Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, mvvm, data-binding

First of all, here is what I am trying to achieve:

I want to have a View that automatically pushes any changes to the SQLite database if any of its Controls' properties change (Simple!).

My logic, which might also be bogus due to lack of experience:

> 1. Add an empty object to the Database
> 2. Get its instance back from the Context
> 3. Bind this instance to the Control (simple TextBox for now)

I expect data to be pushed back to DB when I update my TextBox but nothing happens.

Here is how I do it:

Code excerp:

```
AddBook(new Book ()); // First, add empty object for referencing.

Book book;
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
{
   book = context.Books.OrderByDescending(x => x.BookId).FirstOrDefault();       
}

SelectedBook = book; // My property is now set to the DB object.
```

and binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedBook.BookName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a lot :)

I believe your MyDataContext extends DbContext.
If so, DbContext is supposed to be a "unit of work".
Usually you:

1. Get some data from the database and have EF expose them as collections of objects
2. Modify this collections as needed, adding, removing and editing objects
3. Push the changes to the database calling SaveChanges
4. Dispose the DbContext and start again with a new one

In your sample you are disposing the DbContext as soon as phase 1 end.
EF no longer track your objects, so it will have no idea about what you changed, and will push nothing to the database.

In comments you say "My property is now set to the DB object".
It's not. It's set to an object which was original retrived by EF, but EF "forgot about it" the moment you disposed the DbContext. The object is still there only because you are still referencing it with your "book" variable.

Comment: How do you push an updated object back into database properly?

Comment: DbContext.SaveChanges